# Android : Is it possible to download and install app without getting user permission by using Device Administration

Tags: android, mdm

I want to give a mobile device to 10 employees with Device Administration installed application which is also connected with server. I can select the number of employees from server and i can push the mobile app to the selected employees.

The app should get downloaded and installed without getting the user permission. Is it possible to achieve? If it is yes then please provide me some links and examples. Just I want to restrict what are all the apps they can use it.

Comment: what is `mdm` ?

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko mobile device management pr device administration

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you're looking for is provided by EMM's (Enterprise Mobility Management). Some examples are Airwatch and MobileIron.  Once your devices are provisioned using the EMM's... you can force install certain apps silently, enforce VPN's, security restrictions, track location and usage, lock the phone, and wipe data.

https://www.mobileiron.com/
http://www.air-watch.com/